# iPhone 6 iOS 8 keyboard not showing while the UITextField is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, device-orientation

***This is happening with real iPhone 6 device and not simulator.***

In my application, some view controllers supports both portrait and landscape orientations. The application is working just fine on iPhone 5 (iOS 8). On iPhone 6 when I change orientation from portrait to landscape and then back to portrait and then after pushing next view controller the keyboard is not showing while the UITextField is active. Keyboard is not showing on screen at all but when I tapped on bottom it shows digits being written on Textfield. So Keyboards position has changed and it is not visible on screen at all. I have not optimised my application for iPhone 6 and using native scaling. Can someone suggest me any possible solution???

Comment: This is happening with real device or simulator?

Answer (score 0):

This is bug of iOS Simulator.

To see the keyboard, just press Cmd (⌘) + K

You are done.

Comment: No mate I am experiencing this behaviour on iPhone 6 device not on simulator :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to hardware --> keyboard and untick connect hardware keyboard

Comment: I am experiencing this behaviour on iPhone 6 device not on simulator :(

Answer (score 0):

It is bug of iOS Simulator do this as per image shown

[image]

Comment: I am experiencing this behaviour on iPhone 6 device not on simulator :(

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I did to fix when the iPhone keypad was invisible or Missing:

1. Do a hard reset Switch off Bluetooth(this worked for me).
2. May be Reboot once.
3. Check for jailbreak tweak updates, if your device is jailbroken(not
   in my case).
4. Restore.

This helped me resolving this issue on my device:[igeeksblog](http://www.igeeksblog.com/iphone-ipad-keyboard-missing-or-not-appearing-heres-how-to-fix-it/)